# How to query in sqlite using like keyword with column name?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, android-sqlite, sql-like

Assume I've the following table in sqlite database

Table name A with column A1 and A2

[image]

Table name B with column B1 and B2

[image]

I want to query like following

```
SELECT A1 FROM A, B WHERE A.A2 LIKE '%'+B.B2+'%' AND B.B1 = 1
```

I need the result of 2 rows which contains 1,4

But always it returns 0 rows.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: `/` separated items is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string concatenation operator in SQLite is `||`.  And you can express this as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A1
FROM A JOIN
     B 
     ON A.A2 LIKE '%' || B.B2 || '%' 
WHERE B.B1 = 1;
```

Note that `||` is the **SQL standard** string concatenation operator.  `+` is overloaded in just a handful of databases owned by Microsoft (mostly).

Comment: Wow it works great. I tried string concatination using +, concat keyword, [ ] square brackets. nothing worked. Finally || this works. Thanks @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for this sample data a condition like:

```
A.A2 LIKE '%' || B.B2 || '%'
```

will work, but in general the condition should include the separator `'/'` of the items.

For example if you have a row in `A` with `A2` equal to `'\aa\bb\'` then the above condition will return incorrect results if you search for `'a'`, because `'\aa\bb\' LIKE '%a%'` is `TRUE`.
You can check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8c7d3b3c8db8781035c757e0783ccb28) how you will get wrong results.

So you must use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1
FROM A INNER JOIN B 
ON A.A2 LIKE '%/' || B.B2 || '/%' 
WHERE B.B1 = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2579e4ad3176fb38ac2074a8bc778381).
Results:

```
> | A1 |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> |  4 |
```